# Enable pylint in Netbeans

Tags: python, netbeans, pylint

How can I integrate pylint with netbeans?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a Java IDE for python?

Comment: @Jeffrey: Netbeans is not a pure Java IDE, it has modes for C/C++, Ruby and Python, too.  Granted, the Python mode is not as sophisticated as the Java part, still, it's already useful and it's getting better with every release.

Comment: @Jeffrey: So what should I use, an IDE written in Python?

Comment: I assume you don't want to implement support for pylint yourself.  Still, if it happens so, you could start by learning from the following project that integrates some other style checker.  As I expected, a lot of code is needed (ah, the simplicity of doing something like this for Emacs!), although probably much of it is generated.  Here's the project: http://www.sickboy.cz/checkstyle/

Comment: That comment is borderline to being classified as a YouTube comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a PyLint plugin for [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/). It's a nice little open source IDE for aimed particularly for Python and Ruby. Perhaps you will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but this website:

http://jpydbg.sourceforge.net/

seems to document a method to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

On the netbeans-python (nbpython) dev list there seems to be a whole thread about this:
http://markmail.org/message/rrjcooygoleufje6

So, seemingly, it's not ready yet.

In light of that, you might want to check out the alternatives: http://meandubuntu.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/in-search-of-a-python-ide/